# Using "not only"

Tags: grammaticality

I hear word today from Trump, He said:

> "Not only have thousands of JOBS been created in USA, we’re shipping freedom and opportunity abroad!"

I have three questions:

1. most of time we use NOT ONLY with Also or BUT ALSO, but I have seen many times that native speakers did not use this grammar not. Help me please to use NOT ONLY correctly.
2. the capital letters for example "JOBS" its just for emphasis?
3. It happens to also be Stefano's aftershave., a native speaker use this structure, "to also be some one 's aftershave" how he applied this word.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The 'but also' is optional. You could rephrase the example sentence as follows: "Not only have thousands of jobs been created in USA, *but* we're *also* shipping..."
2. Correct, it is just for emphasis.
3. "It happens to be..." means the same as, "It is..." but suggests that what follows is just some extra information that's not as important to the main point or that it's something which is true by luck or coincidence. For example, "This film was the most expensive film ever made. It also happens to be my dad's favourite." Telling you that it's my dad's favourite is just extra information, not really relevant to it being the most expensive film. Or, "You're from Taunton?! That happens to be where my girlfriend is from." In this case it's a surprising coincidence.

Comment: Some one comment on the tweeter like this "It happens to also be Stefano's aftershave", I couldn't understand the grammar and the meaning of the sentence

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank my friend, completely understood